# What are the signs of an impending private equity exit strategy?

Tags: acquisition, exit-planning

I work for a company that is private equity (PE) backed and has primarily grown over the last 5 years through mergers and acquisitions (M&As). In fact, I joined the company via one of the acquisitions about 1.5 years ago.

I know that the main 3 exit strategies for the investors are:

1. Sell the company to a competitor.
2. Go public and cash out post-IPO.
3. Sell the company to another PE firm via a secondary leveraged buyout.

What I'm hoping people here can answer is, what are the signs that one of the 3 above items is impending, and are there any signs as to which one of the 3 is most likely?

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: When you see guys in the lobby with briefcases full of cash and your boss in Bermuda shorts and a floral shirt.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good sign. Unfortunately, that's the one downside of being fully remote, no ability to see strangers walking in or execs walking out!

Comment: Do you know who the private equity investors are and how they have exited previous investments?

Comment: I left the exit-planning tag on your question on the assumption that you're trying to figure out when to jump ship. Is this correct?

Comment: You are unlikely to know unless you're at least peripherally involved in discussions where the names of any those topics might come up. PE backed companies regularly expand and contract. I'd watching for phrases like "pause on hiring", "re-evaluate spending" or anything else that signals the people at the top are watching the finances super closely and/or pinching pennies.

Comment: Even if you are in those discussions your likely will be limited in acting on that information. Part of the reason those discussions are even happening is likely due to your own efforts.

Comment: @BSMP: You are correct, I'm hoping to spot the signs early on so I can leave on my own terms before I have to go through another M&A.

Comment: @mattfreake: I don't know who the PE investors are (and the company put a lot of effort into keeping that information from us).

Comment: @JoelEtherton: So far they've been pretty unwilling to spend any money on anything other than new acquisitions (buying them, not on integrating them properly) or investments in tools for the new Sales team, so no changes but they did start out pretty tight.

Comment: @Mr.E with the economy as it is, this sounds like a blitzscaling model except for the absence of blind hiring. There will come a point where this expansion will require retraction and there will be layoffs. It's a matter of timing only.

Comment: This wiki post has some humorous answers to your question: https://wiki.c2.com/?WarningSignsOfCorporateDoom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To know which exit strategy they are likely to use, you need to research the private equity firm and see how they have historically exited from their investments.  Obviously, there is a chance that they don't follow a specific pattern and even if they do there is nothing preventing them from using a different strategy for your current company.

As to signs that one of these items is pending, being that you are a remote worker it would largely depend on your role at the company or who you know.

Depending on your role, you may receive unusual requests or notice uncommon audits related to your role.  For example, if you are working in the IT side, they may want to do an unscheduled security posture check or penetration test ( assuming your company regularly performs these ).  Maybe you work in the accounting or financial side and the PE begins asking for more than usual figures, forecasts,....etc.

The easiest way is if you know someone high in your company's hierarchy and have a good enough relationship where if they knew about some impending event they would have no issue mentioning or discussing with you.

Unfortunately, other than researching the PE yourself, the others will likely be mostly out of your control.  Just do your job and try not to worry about it.  Remember that the question isn't if the exit will happen, it's when.